# Calculate integral using keyhole contour

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I want to compute $\int_{0}^\infty \frac{x^{1/2}logx}{(1+x)^2}dx$. To do this, I considered $f(z)=\frac{z^{1/2}logz}{(1+z)^2}$, with $logz=log|z| + i argz$, $0<argz<2\pi$.

So I integrated along the stardard keyhole contour (see relevant image) [image]

I have shown that the integral on the small circle and on the big circle go to zero as the radius of the big circle goes to infinity and the radius of the small circle goes to zero.

So by Cauchy's Residue Theorem $\int_\Gamma \frac{z^{1/2}logz}{(1+z)^2} dz = 2\pi i Res(f; -1) = 2 \pi i \frac{\pi - 2i}{2} = \pi ^2 i + 2\pi$.

So $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{1/2}logz}{(1+z)^2} dz = \pi ^2 i + 2\pi$, but this should be $\pi$. Where have I gone wrong? Can someone help me?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2895399/the-integral-of-frac-logxx3-41x-from-zero-to-infinity-using-conto?rq=1